# Is this code safe? (linked list, C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list

The following code seems to work ok to remove a node from a linked list:

```
bool remove(node * & head, int toBeRemoved)
{
 if (head == nullptr)  //empty list
        return false;
    else {
        node * temp = head;

        //the first node needs to be removed
        if (head->data == toBeRemoved) { 
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
            return true;
        }

        //seek for node and remove it
        else {
            while (temp->next != nullptr && temp->next->data != toBeRemoved)
                temp = temp->next;
            if (temp->next->data == toBeRemoved){
                node * removeThis = temp->next;
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
                delete removeThis;
                return true;
            }

            //data to be removed can't be found in the list
            else
                if (temp->next == nullptr && temp->next->data != toBeRemoved)
                    return false;
        }
    }
}
```

(I understand there's a list implementation in C++ but I'm only trying to understand this algorithm here, not replace it with something else).

Even though the code works when deleting a node placed at the beginning, in between or at the end of the list and I don't see any errors, I still have some doubts about the following line: `if (temp->next->data == toBeRemoved)`.

Since that whole block can be executed when the node to be deleted is the last node (i.e.: `temp->next==nullptr`) I'm wondering how safe it is to attempt to access `temp->next->data`.

And even if it's safe, is it a bad programming practice?

Comment: Does the code you show work? Do you just want a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: The code does work. It removes elements from the list successfully. But I'd like to know if the line I'm pinpointing is safe, and if it's good practice to use it that way.

Comment: You don't need the last `if`. When the `while` loop ends, either you found the element to remove, or it can't be found. The `if` before that checks for the first case, so the only other possibility is the second.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for code review, which is better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If it seems to be working and you are wondering if it is good/ bad practice, code review would be the better place for this question.

Comment: Code is actually broken, and as such is not a good candidate for Code Review. It'll break if trying to remove an element not found in the list.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Just because it seems to be working doesn't mean it is. See my answer for his bugs.

Comment: In terms of coding style, keep your if and else together, and indented on the same levels. Always use braces. (At least, as a beginner.) :-)

Comment: Even though there is answer below I'd recommend going to code review anyway. Indentation aside it would be much cleaner with single if and for loop. It would be easier to spot errors as well.

Comment: Also, is there a reason your function takes a reference to a pointer to a node i.e. `node * & head`? I think what you want is `bool remove(node * head, int toBeRemoved)`.

Comment: @tylerparsons that reference is there in case the first node needs to be removed (i.e., the head pointer would change). Is that not correct?

Comment: I see, I suppose it's technically correct, but the design is a bit confusing/easy to misuse.  Let's say you have a global `const node * HEAD;`. In some function you write `node * h = HEAD; remove(h, h->data);`.  `HEAD` will not be updated in this case. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that line is not safe.

The `while` loop ends when either `temp->next` is a null pointer, or `temp->next->data` contains the value to be removed. If it ends for the first reason, then accessing `temp->next->data` is invalid, because it's indirecting through a null pointer.

You should change the order of the test after the `while` loop ends. Check for the null pointer first. If it's not a null pointer, it means you found the element, and you can remove it.

```
        while (temp->next != nullptr && temp->next->data != toBeRemoved) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (temp->next == nullptr) { // data couldn't be found
            return false;
        } else { // data was found, remove it
            node * removeThis = temp->next;
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            delete removeThis;
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I misunderstood which line you were asking about. I'm rewriting my answer.